# Can $a \cos A + b \cos B + c \cos C$ equal $4 \sin A \sin B \sin C$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1102050/409) about an identity with the sides and angles of a triangle.

---

> Can $a \cos A + b \cos B + c \cos C$ equal $4R \sin A \sin B \sin C$?

I'm not sure if this is possible. Is it?

R is the circumradius.

Comment: what are $a,b,c$ and $A,B,C$ ?

Comment: You need a circumradius factor on the right-hand side.

Comment: @Blue: Oops, I forgot to add that. I will fix that. But how would I prove that?

Comment: @r9m: a, b, and c are sides of a triangle. A, B, and C are the angles corresponding to the sides.

Comment: Once $a$, $b$, $c$ are written as $2 R \sin A$, $2 R\sin B$, $2 R\sin C$, so that the left-hand side equals $R(\sin 2A + \sin 2B+\sin 2C)$, this question becomes [a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/154505/409).

Comment: @Blue: How can $a \cos A + b \cos B + c \ cos C = R(\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C)$, though? I understand the second part, where $R(\sin 2A + \sin 2B + \sin 2C) = 4R \sin A \sin B \sin C$.

Comment: $a \cos A = 2 R\sin A \cos A = R ( 2\sin A\cos A) = R \sin 2A$.

Comment: @Blue: Got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$a,b,c,A,B,C=0$$
works. Probably not the solution you were looking for though.

Comment: @MathNoob: No, not really, haha. I was asking it for this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102050/prove-fraca-sin-ab-sin-bc-sin-ca-cos-ab-cos-bc-cos-c-r-left-fraca2/1102070?noredirect=1#comment2247087_1102070 , where one of the answers mentioned that those two were equal.